# Web services consumption and calling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, c#-4.0

I want to ask how can I add web service into my already existing MVC 4.0 project? I have searched on Internet, in all the links they are saying to create a new application/solution but I want to add a web service and how It will be available to call from other web sites. Can somebody please tell me the steps for it. I will be thankful to you. I just have basic knowledge of .Net.

2)Suppose I have to call a web service from another site so how will I able to call that service if I do not have my own?

I have searched following links:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/aspnet-web-service-or-creating-and.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337535/Understanding-the-Basics-of-Web-Service-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

Everything is rather simple. Just read a lot about WCF service(not joking).
 But for the beginning you can add service reference to any .Net project just by adding `webservice reference`. Take a look at this [article](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1409/adding-wcf-service-references.aspx). Or you can generate wcf client's code via svcutil. Here is another [article](http://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/generating-wcf-service-proxy-classes-using-svcutil/).

You can consume WCF on any .Net app, either web or win. You just have to generate you wcf client and configure binding and endpoint setting. But I'd strongly recomment you to read some books about WCF. At least take Jeffrey Richter's - CLR via C# or Andrew Troelsen - C# and the .NET Platform and read WCF chapters to have common knowledges.

UPDATE:

It's now a huge difference working with WCF in MVC or any other project. Once you have generated a client, or you have your web reference - you do have an opportunity to call remote services via client. And you can use MVC controller to run it. E.g.

```
 public ActionResult TestAction()
 {
   var(INewlyGeneratedClient client = new NewlyGeneratedClient("<here specify endpoint name>")
   {
     client.RunTestMethod();
   }
   return null;
 }
```

Keep in mind that all webservice configuration data might me located in `web.config` file. Make sure you have section `bindings` and `endpoint`.

Comment: Sir, It's About working in MVC. It's not about WCF and I do'nt know WCF. Please Explain me in reference to MVC.